# Long time stability in nested Bochner spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $V\subset H$ be densely, compactly and continuously embedded, which, among others, means that $$\|x\|_H \leq \|x\|_V\quad (*)$$ for all $x\in V $.

I have the following stability estimates for a *solution* $v\in L^2 ((0,\infty); V )$ and a *right hand side* $f\in ((0,\infty); H)$:

1. For any time $T > 0$, it holds that $$\|v\|_{L^2 ((0,T); V)} \leq C_T \|f\|_{L^2 ((0,T); H)}$$ with a constant $C_T$ depending on $T$
2. In the weaker norm: $$\|v\|_{L^2 ((0,\infty); H)} \leq C_\infty \|f\|_{L^2 ((0,\infty); H)}$$

Does this somehow imply that also 
$$\|v\|_{L^2 ((0,\infty); V)} \leq \tilde C_\infty \|f\|_{L^2 ((0,\infty); H)}\quad(?)$$

---

**edit**: with constants $C_T, C_\infty, \tilde C_\infty$ independent of $f$.

---

I am convinced that such an estimate should hold in general since, by 2.), $v(t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$ and, at least in my case with $H=L^2(\Omega)$ and $V=W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, it holds that 
$$\|x\|_H = 0 \text{ and }x\in V, \text{ then }\|x\|_V=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $v_n(t, x) = f_n(t, x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \theta_k(t) \lambda_k^{-1/2} \varphi_k(x)$ composed of eigenpairs of a Laplacian (with summable $\lambda_k^{-1}$) and the indicator function $\theta_k$ of the temporal interval $[k, k + 1]$. I think the sequence $(v_n, f_n)$ satisfies 1. & 2. uniformly but not "Ineq. (?)".

Comment: Good one. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Not too sure, whether this example is *admissible*. Since your $v_\infty$ is not in $L^2((0,\infty);V)$

Comment: OK. I think your example does **not** give a definite answer to my question. Since it is assumed that $v\in L^2((0,\infty);V)$. So it cannot be the limit of a construction like you proposed.

Comment: @Jan: I'm not talking about a limit. Presumably, you have the constants $C_T$ and $C_\infty$ independent of $f$ (on which $v$ depends in some unique way), and you hope to obtain a $\tilde{C}_\infty$ independent of $f$ also; the sequence shows that's not possible without further specification (like, what's the eqn $v \mapsto f$). If this is not what you're looking for, I suggest to clarify in the question.

Comment: I see - thanks. I will adapt my answer, such that your answer fits.